# module verification failed: signature and/or > required key missing - tainting kernel

Tags: drivers, kernel

I am new to Linux device drivers. After installing the driver in Ubuntu 14.04, I'm seeing this in `dmesg` or my module:

```
module verification failed: signature and/or required key missing-tainting kernel
```

I followed [this guide on the gentoo wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Signed_kernel_module_support). I didn't have the same problem in Ubuntu 12.04.

Following the guide resulted in another warning message like

```
UNKNOWN request key:"some key".
```

How can I resolve this problem?